# Android API 28 Add fragment after RemoveAllViews

Tags: xamarin.android, mvvmcross, fragmentmanager

I am change the tabs in the app, I want to remove all the views from the current Framelayout and then, to add the view that I am navigating to.

Everything works as expected on API 21, API 24 (as I tested) but on latest API version 28, after I remove the inner views, it does not add the new fragment.

I added a breakpoint to see if the code reaches to the transaction where I am adding the fragment and it does.

This is where I remove all the views:

```
 var fragment = FragmentManager.FindFragmentByTag(tag);
                if (fragment != null)
                {
                    RunOnUiThread(() =>
                    {
                        ((FrameLayout)FindViewById(Resource.Id.actualtabcontent)).RemoveAllViewsInLayout();
                    });
                    Presenter?.ChangeTab((MvxFragment)fragment);
                }
```

This is where I add the new one

```
var transaction = _fragmentManager.BeginTransaction();


            if (fragment.IsAdded)
            {
                transaction.Remove(fragment);
            }

            transaction
                .Add(Resource.Id.actualtabcontent, fragment)
                .AddToBackStack(fragment.GetType().Name)
                .Commit();
```

No code is hit meanwhile.

Again, the app works well on lower version of Android.
On Android API 28 it does not show the new added fragment.

Comment: probably to do with Mvx worth taking a look at their documentation.

Comment: Try to place the change table function:Presenter?.ChangeTab((MvxFragment)fragment); inside the RunOnUIThread function?